# Silverlight ChannelFactory, Credentials and Certificates

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I am trying to secure our WCF services and keep running into issues. We utilize ChannelFactory to make the connection between the silverlight client and the server.

I originally was using TransportWithMessageCredential to send the username and password from the client to the server. I had this working as long as the server that hosted the services and the silverlight client were the same url. Once I changed the url then I received security errors. I setup a crossdomain.xml policy like was suggested in the error, but that didn't fix the issue. After some research I found that if using cross site calls and passing the username that you need to use certificates to secure your messages.

I am now trying to setup the certificates in the client. Due to the client being used at a variety of offices we are unable to install the certificate on each machine. I would like to have this as an embedded resource and then set the certificate when the channelfactory is created. I've seen examples of doing this that suggest the following.

```
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IYourService>();
channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = 
                                     clientCertificate;
```

However, I am not seeing a property for ClientCertificate on Credentials. I only see username.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or is this just not possible in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that my clientaccesspolicy.xml file was incorrect to support SSL. Once I fixed that issue then I was able to use TransportWithMessageCredential security mode and didn't need to have a client certificate installed.

For those having this type of problem your clientaccesspolicy should look like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
 <cross-domain-access>
   <policy>
     <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
       <domain uri="https://*"/>
       <domain uri="http://*"/>
     </allow-from>
     <grant-to>
       <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
     </grant-to>
   </policy>
</cross-domain-access>
```